# SQL - filter out resultset based on value

Tags: sql, oracle

DB - Oracle

All constraints omitted.

```
 create table customer (cid number(10), cname varchar(50));

 create table exercise (eid number(10), ecode varchar(2));

 -- mapping table
 create table customer_exercise (cid number(10), eid number(10), cnt number(10))
```

Data

```
Customer table

100    e1
200    e2
300    e3
400    e4

Exercise table

1      c1
2      c2
3      c3
4      c4

Customer_Exercise

cid  eid count
100   1  20
200   2  50
100   2  30
300   4  10
```

SQL:

```
SELECT   c.cid
        ,e.eid
        ,COALESCE(SUM(ce.cnt), 0) AS total_cnt
    FROM customer c
         CROSS JOIN exercise e
         LEFT JOIN customer_exercise ce
            ON     ce.cid = c.cid
               AND ce.eid = e.eid
   WHERE     c.cid IN (100, 200, 300)
         AND e.eid IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY c.cid, e.eid
```

Result:

```
cid   eid  total_cnt

100    1       20
100    2       30
200    1       0
200    2       50
300    1       0
300    2       0
```

Is there a way to filter out customers with no entries for any exercise ids in the in clause?

For e.g. customer 300 does not have any rows for exercise id 1 or 2. This customer should not be in the result. Customer 200 has no rows for exercise 1, but has data for exercise 2, so he is expected to show up as count 0 for exercise 1.

How do I get a resultset like below?

Expected Result:

```
cid   eid    total_cnt

100    1         20
100    2         30
200    1         0
200    2         50
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an `inner join` instead of outer join, but drop the join condition on the `eid`, moving that into a `CASE WHEN` expression in the `select` clause. This way you'll have to repeat the `in (1, 2)` condition though:

```
SELECT     c.cid
         , e.eid
         , COALESCE(SUM(CASE e.eid WHEN ce.eid THEN ce.cnt ELSE 0 END), 0) AS total_cnt
FROM       (
                SELECT DISTINCT eid
                FROM   exercise 
                WHERE  eid IN (1, 2)) e
CROSS JOIN customer c
INNER JOIN customer_exercise ce
        ON ce.cid = c.cid
       AND ce.eid IN (1, 2)
WHERE      c.cid IN (100, 200, 300)
GROUP BY   c.cid
         , e.eid
ORDER BY   1, 2
```

See it run on [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/BHUOU74405).

Output:

```
cid | eid  | total_cnt
----+------+----------
100 |  1   |     20
100 |  2   |     30
200 |  1   |      0
200 |  2   |     50
```

Alternative:

```
SELECT     c.cid
         , e.eid
         , COALESCE(SUM(CASE e.eid WHEN ce.eid THEN ce.cnt ELSE 0 END), 0) AS total_cnt
FROM       exercise e
CROSS JOIN customer c
INNER JOIN customer_exercise ce
        ON ce.cid = c.cid
       AND ce.eid IN (1, 2)
WHERE      c.cid IN (100, 200, 300)
       AND e.eid IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY   c.cid
         , e.eid
ORDER BY   1, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do it:

```
with t as (
  SELECT   c.cid
          ,e.eid
          ,COALESCE(SUM(ce.cnt), 0) AS total_cnt
                ,count(max(ce.cnt))over(partition by c.cid) ce_cnt
      FROM customer c
           CROSS JOIN exercise e
           LEFT JOIN customer_exercise ce
              ON     ce.cid = c.cid
                 AND ce.eid = e.eid
     WHERE     c.cid IN (100, 200, 300)
           AND e.eid IN (1, 2)
  GROUP BY c.cid, e.eid
  )
select t.cid,t.eid,t.total_cnt from t where t.ce_cnt >0
```

Sorry, there was a slight mistake on my part, (without max() the code gave ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression)

Comment: Thanks, rayne, I fixed it.